# Looking for the part number of the button

Tags: switches, identification, components

Installed in the Acer Aspire 2920 notebook. Does not work at all - pushing at any angle has no effect. Second button (left touchpad one) works properly.

Circuit diagram lists SW-TACT-119-GP / 62.40009.671. Can not find anything using these numbers other than various Wistron circuit diagrams.

Dimensions are (approximately) 6 * 6 * 3 (mm).

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

After taking the closeup pictures I thought that according to the construction the buttons seem to be maintainable. I disassembled all of them - without desoldering the device (only desoldering the top metallic cover's pin), cleaned, assembled back, and now all the buttons function properly.

Comment: need exact dimensions of the foot print, the part number listed is an internal company part number

Comment: Updated question, thank you.

Comment: Exact dimensions on SMT parts need to be measured by calipers to the nearest 0.1mm

Comment: The most critical dimension in this case is the height above the board. Also pay attention to the operating force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-alcoswitch-switches/FSM2JELGEATR/450-2153-2-ND/2400357

My guess is its a TE connectivity part, maybe one like the one shown above.

Comment: You must be right, datasheet matches dimensions.